# Can my chilli plant be saved?

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, potting-soil

[image]

I started observing some white patches on the soil and have been observing practically no growth on my plant. The leaves are also yellowing. I thought it could be root root so I thought of repotting. The soil is extremely wet, as expected. But I also saw these small white patches. Not sure if it is mold? I read about white root root called scelerotina (I think that is what it said) and once that happens it is practically impossible to save the soil and the plant. But there is no browning on the stems. Should I wash the plant and repot with a fresh soil?

P.S - The plant stays outdoor and receives 4-5 hours direct sunlight and indirect light throughout the day. I have used garden soil with compost. I am located in Bangalore, India and it has been raining here quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

These seedlings are extremely crowded already, and they've probably ceased growing because they're competing for nutrients, it's high time they were potted up individually into their own pots.

In fresh compost a bloom of mould isn't unusual and most sorts do no harm to plants as these will be species that consume dead matter, not living plant tissue. You've nothing to lose by replanting them either way; if they do have a harmful fungus, not much will remove it. I wouldn't recommend washing them as the roots at this age are extremely fragile.